# How to integrate React Native with mySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native

I'm new in React Native and I'm trying to integrate my app with mySQL database located inside my hosting provider (digitalocean.com).
I've managed to get the data through nodejs and express but it's actually getting the data where my problem is.

Here how it goes:

I created a routes.js and inserted the following:

> Note: the following credentials are real but is for pure testing and i don't mind sharing.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '134.122.22.176',
    user: 'yannb_9',
    password: 'yannb_9',
    database: 'tiomanGrow'
});

// Starting our app.
const app = express();

connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Connection error message: ' + err.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected!')
    // Creating a GET route that returns data from the 'users' table.
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        // Connecting to the database.
        // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'users' table).
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM farmers', function (error, results, fields) {
            // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
            if (error) throw error;
            // Getting the 'response' from the database and sending it to our route. This is were the data is.
            res.send(results)
        });
    });
});

// Starting our server.
app.listen(3000, () => {

    console.log('Go to http://localhost:3000/farmers so you can see the data.');
});
```

Up until now everything's great! you can click on the http://localhost:3000/farmers and you'll see the data when you run the file.

Here's where I get stuck:
I was to display the data on my app and i have no idea how to possibly do that.
I did a few researches and saw a possible solution which didn't work. it actually gave me a **"Network request failed"**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { HeaderImg } from '../components/HeaderImg';
import { Button } from '../components/Button';

export default class DB extends React.Component {
    state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        errorMessage: null
    };

    fetchData = async() => {
        fetch('http://134.122.22.176:3000/farmers')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(users => console.dir(users))
        .catch(error=> console.log(error))
    }


    render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <HeaderImg />

            <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
            {this.state.errorMessage && (
                <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
            )}
            </View>
            <Button 
            onPress={this.fetchData}
            />
        </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({      
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: on ios or on android?

Comment: this is on android

Comment: are you testing on android OS 9? and is your target-sdk set to 28+?

Comment: Im using expo on Galaxy s10 api 29

Answer (score 1):

The hostname for your MySQL database in your routes.js file is shown as 134.122.22.176. That's the **database** ip address. You **cannot** `fetch` from this IP address. MySQL databases do not respond to standard HTTP requests; they are not web servers.

Your Express app is running on **localhost**: http://localhost:3000/farmers - I am guessing you can surf to that URL in a web browser and see data, for example. If that Express app is running on your development computer, then you just need to find out the IP address (xx.xx.xx.xx) for that computer on your LAN, and use that in your `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 9, google has decided to remove http client library from bootclasspath.

> With Android 6.0, we removed support for the Apache HTTP client. Beginning with Android 9, that library is removed from the bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default.

For brief overview of the changes, [visit](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28).

In order to connect with http client, you have to add this line in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

After that you should be able to connect with HTTP clients with your android Pie device.